# has_many :through relation manipulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm kind of new to rails and I have read and read about has_many_through relationships and I still don't get how to manipulate that! I'm working on an app that has three models: courses, topics, weeks. A course has many topics through weeks and topic can be in many courses also through weeks.

Now my question.  I'd like to, when I create a topic, be able to add some fields for weeks and create also some of the attributes of the week that's the easy part.  Then I want to be able to, in the weeks form or new view, select one course and select several topics that can be on that course.  Of course the topics are already created and the courses as well!  How can I add the courses id to de "weeks" rows that hold the selected topics id!

Comment: Add supporting code to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering these relations:

```
class Week < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :topic
  validates :course_id, :topic_id, presence: true
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weeks
  has_many :courses, through: :weeks
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :weeks
  has_many :topics, through: :weeks
end
```

The `week` form:

```
= form_for @week do |f|
  # your form
  = f.select :course_id, options_for_select(Course.scoped.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] })
  = f.select :topics_ids, options_for_select(Topic.scoped.map{ |t| [t.name, t.id] }), multiple: true
```

Allows us to select one Course and several Topic. But we can't save multiple topic ids inside a single Week record. We have to create a week record for each `[course_id, topic_id]` combination:

In the `weeks_controller`

```
before_filter :sanitize_params, only: [:create, :update]

def create
  params[:week].each do |index, week_attrs|
    Week.create(week_attrs)
  end
  # etc.
end

def update
  params[:week].each do |index, week_attrs|
    Week.find(weeks_attrs.delete(:id)).update_attributes(week_attrs)
  end
  # etc.
end

def sanitize_params
  base_params = params[:week].clone
  params[:week].delete(:topics_ids).each_with_index do |topic_id, i|
    params[:week][i] = base_params.except(:topics_ids).merge(topic_id: topic_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok so your relations are spot on thats how they look! and yes i understand  that one of the records of the weeks table can't have more than one topic, the week has an attribute: week_number, and i need to create ir through the topic form with the label "to be displayed on week number?" so the topic form would create all the records from topic plus that record from week! (i hope im making it clear so far if not let me know)

Comment: now i just want the week form or view to serve as a conector between course and the topics! that by selecting one course and a bunch of topics the course id is saved in each of the weeks record that hold the id of the selected topic! is that posible? and thanks for your response!

Comment: second comment: yes it is possible I already did it in my answer ; first comment: I don't really understand...

Comment: is 'each_with_index' a real method? or what does it mean?

Comment: Yes it is a real method, it allows you to use a index count directly in oneline instead of creating a variable equal to zero and then increment it in the iterator's loop

Comment: yeah i read up on it yesterday! once i got what everithing did (like i said new to rails) i did what you told me! just one problem though it says that each_with index is undefined for nil class! i'm assuming that i have to declare that class there? but idk where :s (thanks and sorry for the rails noobness jeje)